# Created a button using a Tutorial on Intellij what is wrong with the code?

Tags: javascript, html

as the title suggests. what im trying to do is get my button to show or hide the above text ( on my Tutorial Quiz page), by clicking the button. So what happens is the text shows. but when i click the button it will not hide.

Here is my html code for "Tutorial Quiz" Page

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa+One|Open+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <script src="quizconfig.js">
    </script>

    <script>
        var actualchoices=new Array()
        document.cookie="ready=yes"
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<header>
    <a href="Tutorial Quiz.html" id="logo">
        <h1>Webprograming Quiz</h1>
        <h2>by Chris Moore</h2>
    </a>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Tutorial.html">Tutorial</a></li>
            <li><a href="Tutorial Quiz.html"class="selected">Quiz</a></li>
            <li><a href="Feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div id="wrapper">
    <p align="center">

    <form method="POST" name="myquiz">

        <font face="Arial"><big><big>General Knowledge Quiz</big></big></font></p>

    <div class="qheader">1) What is the colour of Irn-Bru</div>

    <div class="qselections">
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="question1">a) Orange.<br>
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="question1">b) Red.<br>
        <input type="radio" value="c" name="question1">c) Green.<br>
        <input type="radio" value="d" name="question1">d) Purple.<br>
    </div>
    <div id="target"> This is the hint you want to hide</div>

    <button type="button" id="toggle">Get Hint</button>

    <script>
        var button = document.getElementById ("toggle");
        var target = document.getElementById("target");
        var bool = true;

        function displayToggle() {
            if (bool) {
                target.setAttribute("class", "hide");
                bool = false;
            } else {
                target.setAttribute("class", "show");
                bool = true;
            }
        }
        button.addEventListener("click",displayToggle, false);
    </script>




    <br>
    <div class="qheader">
        2) What is the world's most common religion?</div>
    <div class="qselections">
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="question2">a) Christianity<br>
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="question2">b) Buddhism<br>
        <input type="radio" value="c" name="question2">c) Hinduism<br>
        <input type="radio" value="d" name="question2">d) Muslim<br>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="qheader">
        3) Which city ranks as the world's most populous city (2002)?</div>
    <div class="qselections">
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="question3">a) New York (US)<br>
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="question3">b) Mexico City (Mexico)<br>
        <input type="radio" value="c" name="question3">c) Tokyo (Japan)<br>
        <input type="radio" value="d" name="question3">d) Shanghai (China)<br>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="qheader">
        4) What is the second largest country (in size) in the world?</div>
    <div class="qselections">
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="question4">a) USA<br>
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="question4">b) China<br>
        <input type="radio" value="c" name="question4">c) Canada<br>
        <input type="radio" value="d" name="question4">d) Russia<br>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="qheader">
        5) As of January 2003, how much is Microsoft Chairman Bill Gates's net worth?</div>
    <div class="qselections">
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="question5">a) 10 million US<br>
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="question5">b) 10 billion US<br>
        <input type="radio" value="c" name="question5">c) 35 billion US<br>
        <input type="radio" value="d" name="question5">d) 50 billion US<br>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="qheader">
        6) Which country below is not one of the members of the UN security council (Jan 2003)?</div>
    <div class="qselections">
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="question6">a) USA<br>
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="question6">b) China<br>
        <input type="radio" value="c" name="question6">c) Germany<br>
        <input type="radio" value="d" name="question6">d) France<br>
    </div>

    <br>

    <form>
        <div align="center">
            <input type="button" value="Grade Me!" name="B1" onClick="gradeit()"> <input type="button" value="Reset" name="B2" onClick="document.myquiz.reset()"></div>
    </form>
    <footer>
        <a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="img/twitter-wrap.png" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="img/facebook-wrap.png" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
        <p>&copy; 2014 Chris Moore.</p>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Here of my Javascript for making a feedback page

```
//Enter total number of questions:
var totalquestions=6

//Enter the solutions corresponding to each question:
var correctchoices=new Array()
correctchoices[1]='c' //question 1 solution
correctchoices[2]='a' //question 2 solution, and so on.
correctchoices[3]='c'
correctchoices[4]='c'
correctchoices[5]='c'
correctchoices[6]='c'

/////Don't edit beyond here//////////////////////////

function gradeit(){
var incorrect=null
for (q=1;q<=totalquestions;q++){
    var thequestion=eval("document.myquiz.question"+q)
    for (c=0;c<thequestion.length;c++){
        if (thequestion[c].checked==true)
        actualchoices[q]=thequestion[c].value
        }

    if (actualchoices[q]!=correctchoices[q]){ //process an incorrect choice
        if (incorrect==null)
        incorrect=q
        else
        incorrect+="/"+q
        }
    }

if (incorrect==null)
incorrect="a/b"
document.cookie='q='+incorrect
if (document.cookie=='')
alert("Your browser does not accept cookies. Please adjust your browser settings.")
else
window.location="Feedback.html"
}


function showsolution(){
var win2=window.open("","win2","width=200,height=350, scrollbars")
win2.focus()
win2.document.open()
win2.document.write('<title>Solution</title>')
win2.document.write('<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">')
win2.document.write('<center><h3>Solution to Quiz</h3></center>')
win2.document.write('<center><font face="Arial">')
for (i=1;i<=totalquestions;i++){
for (temp=0;temp<incorrect.length;temp++){
if (i==incorrect[temp])
wrong=1
}
if (wrong==1){
win2.document.write("Question "+i+"="+correctchoices[i].fontcolor("red")+"<br>")
wrong=0
}
else
win2.document.write("Question "+i+"="+correctchoices[i]+"<br>")
}
win2.document.write('</center></font>')
win2.document.write("<h5>Note: The solutions in red are the ones to the questions you had incorrectly answered.</h5><p align='center'><small><a href='http://www.javascriptkit.com' target='_new'>JavaScript Kit quiz script</a></small>")
win2.document.close()
}
```

---

### Here is my main.css

```
/*************************
GENERAL
**************************/

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 5%;
}

#img {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 5%;
}


a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}



/*************************
HEADING
**************************/

header {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Changa One', sans-serif;
    margin: 15px 0;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 0.8em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    margin: -5px 0 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}




/*************************
Navigation
**************************/

nav {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 20px 0 0 ;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 15px 10px;
}



/*************************
FOOTER
**************************/

footer {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    padding-top:50px;
    color:#F5F5F5;
}

.social-icon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}


/*************************
PAGE: Images
**************************/

#gallery {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#gallery li {
    float: left;
    width: 28%;
    margin:2.5%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color:#bdc3c7;
}

#gallery li a p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5%;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #bdc3c7
}

#gallery1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#gallery1 li {
    float: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin:2.5%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color:#bdc3c7;
}

#gallery1 li a p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5%;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #000
}

#gallery2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 330px;
    list-style: none;
}

#gallery2 li {
    float: left;
    width: 28%;
    margin:1%;
    background-color: #A0A8A8;
    color:#bdc3c7;
}

#gallery2 li a {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0.5%;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #000
}

#gallery3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 210px;
    list-style: none;
}

#gallery3 li {
    float: left;
    width: 28%;
    margin:1%;
    background-color: #A0A8A8;
    color:#bdc3c7;
}

#gallery3 li a {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0.5%;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #000
}

/*************************
COLORS
**************************/

/* site body */
body {
    background-color:#A0A8A8;
    color: #000000;
}

/* green header */
header {
    background: #959E9E;
    border-color: #A6B4B5;
}

/* nav background on mobile devices */
nav{
    background: #959E9E;
}

/* logo text */
h1, h2 {
    color:#F5F5F5;
}

/* links */
a {
    color: #6ab47b;
}

/* nav link */
nav a, nav a:visited {
    color: #fff;
}

/* selected nav link */
nav a.selected, nav a:hover {
    color:#4D4D4D;
}

/*HINT SHOW/HIDE*/
.hide{
    display: hidden;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

---

### Here is my feedback page ( working as intended)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial Feedback</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa+One|Open+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <a href="Feedback.html" id="logo">
        <h1>Feedback</h1>
        <h2>by Chris Moore</h2>
    </a>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Tutorial.html">Tutorial</a></li>
            <li><a href="Tutorial Quiz.html">Quiz</a></li>
            <li><a href="Feedback.html"class="selected">Feedback</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>


<p align="center"><strong><font face="Arial">

    <script src="quizconfig.js">
    </script>

    <big>Instant Quiz Results</big></font></strong></p>
<div align="center"><center>

    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="100%"><form method="POST" name="result"><table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" height="116">
                <tr>
                    <td height="25" bgcolor="#A0A8A8"><strong><font face="Arial"># of questions you got right:</font></strong></td>
                    <td height="25"><p><input type="text" name="p" size="24"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="17" bgcolor="#B2B9B9"><strong><font face="Arial">The questions you got wrong:</font></strong></td>
                    <td height="17"><p><textarea name="T2" rows="3" cols="24" wrap="virtual"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="25" bgcolor="#B2B9B9"><strong><font face="Arial">Grade in percentage:</font></strong></td>
                    <td height="25"><input type="text" name="q" size="8"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center></div>

<form method="POST"><div
        align="center"><center><p>

    <script>
        var wrong=0
        for (e=0;e<=2;e++)
            document.result[e].value=""

        var feedback=document.cookie.split(";")
        for (n=0;n<=feedback.length-1;n++){
            if (feedback[n].charAt(1)=='q')
                parse=n

        }

        var incorrect=feedback[parse].split("=")
        incorrect=incorrect[1].split("/")
        if (incorrect[incorrect.length-1]=='b')
            incorrect=""
        document.result[0].value=totalquestions-incorrect.length+" out of "+totalquestions
        document.result[2].value=(totalquestions-incorrect.length)/totalquestions*100+"%"
        for (temp=0;temp<incorrect.length;temp++)
            document.result[1].value+=incorrect[temp]+", "


    </script>

    <input type="button" value="Take the quiz again" name="B1"
           onClick="location.href='Tutorial Quiz.html'"> <input type="button" value="View solution" name="B2"
                                            onClick="showsolution()"></p>
</center></div>
</form>

<footer>
    <a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="img/twitter-wrap.png" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
    <a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="img/facebook-wrap.png" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
    <p>&copy; 2014 Chris Moore.</p>
</footer>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing you can do to help eliminate some possible issues is make sure you end your statements with a ';'. Also, use {} for all your for loops and conditionals, even if they are only one line. Indenting blocks of code between {} will make it easier for us to read through your code as well.

Comment: And you win the medal for fixing it!. thanks so much!, i can't belive it was something that simple. Is there anything i can do on this site to give you merit or something?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the braces on your function definition:

```
<script>
    var button = document.getElementById ("toggle")
    var target = document.getElementById("target")
    var bool = true;

    function displayToggle() {  // Added '{' here
        if (bool) {
            target.setAttribute("class", "hide");
            bool = false;
        } else {
            target.setAttribute("class", "show");
            bool = true;
        }
    } // Added this line
    button.addEventListener("click",displayToggle, false);
</script>
```

It looks like your css may be different than what you originally posted as well. Try updating your .hide class:

```
/*HINT SHOW/HIDE*/
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: That wasnt it. nothing changed unfortunetly.

Comment: none that is coming up no. Thats what i dont really understand.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with my changes in your code and it appears to be working. Is there something else on the page that could be messing with it?  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1pzxqv3s/)

Comment: @Chris I would have to see your code to be able to say that. If you aren't getting any errors then it is probably something misspelled somewhere. It could also be that you are attaching handlers to an element that doesn't have the events triggered on it.

Comment: il edit my topic with my full code on the main 3 pages i think are relevent. if you cant find it maybe someone else might be able to.